# Counting instances of cargo within two ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of cargo by length and weight, and I'm trying to get source data for a chart to show how the weight is distributed within each length window.

The cargo is between 14 and 21 metres long, and lengths are to be displayed in metre classes - 14-15, 15-16 and so on.
The weights are between 30 and 100 metric tonnes, to be illustrated in 10-tonne segments.

I currently have quantities (to integers), lengths (to three decimals) and weights (to kg integers) in ranges called `Lengths` and `Weights`.

[image: Starting data]

I have the starts of the windows in columns **H** (Length) and **J** (Weight), with the count intended to appear in column **K** (Count). So far I've constructed this formula (this one in **K2**):

```
=COUNTIFS(Lengths, ">="&$H2, Lengths, "<"&$H2&"+1", Weights, ">="&$J2, Weights, "<"&$J2&"+10000")
```

Leaving the cell references inside the quotes just kept the same references all the way down, but breaking them out as above doesn't seem to have made any difference. The formula above also doesn't take quantities (in column **A**) into account.

I suspect `SUMPRODUCT` would be a better way of going about it, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've looked it up in a few places, but really only managed to confuse myself...

How can I make it give me a reliable count?

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the math part from the quotes: `"<"&$H2&"+1"` should be `"<"&$H2+1` and also `"<"&$J2&"+10000"` should be `"<"&$J2+10000`

You are trying to find when it is lower than the string `14 + 1` not the number `15`.

```
=COUNTIFS(Lengths, ">="&$H2, Lengths, "<"&$H2+1, Weights, ">="&$J2, Weights, "<"&$J2+10000)
```

To take the quantities into the formula use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(Quantity, Lengths, ">="&$H2, Lengths, "<"&$H2+1, Weights, ">="&$J2, Weights, "<"&$J2+10000)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (By the way, any idea on how I can take quantities into account?)

Comment: Change the formula to a SUMIFS() with the column you want to sum as Quantity.

Answer (score 1):

This takes into account the quantities:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A$1:A$6*(lengths>=H1)*(lengths<H8)*(weights>=J1)*(weights<J2))
```

(assuming that the next length bin starts in row 8).

Comment: Thanks! I went with the SUMIFS on this occasion, but you've got me curious to learn how to use SUMPRODUCT more.